# SqlAlchemy: count of distinct over multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, count, sqlalchemy, distinct, aggregate-functions

I can't do:

```
>>> session.query(
        func.count(distinct(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent)).first()
TypeError: distinct() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I can do:

```
session.query(
        func.count(distinct(func.concat(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent))).first()
```

Which is fine (count of unique users in a 'pageload' db table).

This isn't correct in the general case, e.g. will give a count of 1 instead of 2 for the following table:

```
 col_a | col_b
----------------
  xx   |  yy
  xxy  |  y
```

Is there any way to generate the following SQL (which is valid in postgresql at least)?

```
SELECT count(distinct (col_a, col_b)) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The exact query can be produced using the [`tuple_()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) construct:

```
session.query(
    func.count(distinct(tuple_(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent)))).scalar()
```

Answer (score 25):

`distinct()` accepts more than one argument when appended to the query object:

```
session.query(Hit).distinct(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent).count()
```

It should generate something like:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (hit.ip_address, hit.user_agent)
hit.ip_address AS hit_ip_address, hit.user_agent AS hit_user_agent
FROM hit) AS anon_1
```

which is even a bit closer to what you wanted.

Comment: This generates me a distinct select on all of the columns as well, not just the added ones as parameters.

Comment: You don't need to do query(Hit). Instead you need to do query(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent), then SQLA will treat it right.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like sqlalchemy distinct() accepts only one column or expression.

Another way around is to use `group_by` and `count`. This should be more efficient than using `concat` of two columns - with group by database would be able to use indexes if they do exist:

```
session.query(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent).\
    group_by(Hit.ip_address, Hit.user_agent).count()
```

Generated query would still look different from what you asked about:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM (SELECT hittable.user_agent AS hittableuser_agent, hittable.ip_address AS sometable_column2 
FROM hittable GROUP BY hittable.user_agent, hittable.ip_address) AS anon_1
```

Comment: Very good. Wouldn't have thought of this approach as it's a lot of typing when in SQL.. when in SQLA, it's very easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some variables or characters in concat function in order to make it distinct. Taking your example as reference it should be:

```
session.query(
  func.count(distinct(func.concat(Hit.ip_address, "-", Hit.user_agent))).first()
```